# Problem with if statement in javascript using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, discord.js

I wanted to make the bot read messages and reply if the message contains a certain string, but every time I try to console.log() the message that the function received as a parameter it was a void string. What is the problem?

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client(
    { intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] }
)

client.login("")

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot ONLINE");
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    console.log(message)
    if( message.content == "the condition"){
        message.channel.send("the message");
    }
})
```

This is what the VSC terminal shows when i console.log(message)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hlZ5.png)

Comment: You need the MessageContent intent.

Comment: See [Enabling Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) in the guide.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work. Now it also doesn't execute. Terminal gives me that message: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.
    at WebSocketManager.createShards

Comment: It's because you haven't enabled the message content intent on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. It was my mate that forgot to check the message content intent in discord dev dashboard.